# Qt QVBoxLayout's addStretch strech is taking too much space (from the layout)

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a QVBoxLayout which has a QSCrollArea and with addStretch() added to its end.

QScrollArea here gets to use only half of the available space eventhough there is free space below,, currently occupied by addStretch.

If contents of the QScrollArea are large enough, I want QScrollArea to expand to all the available space. When QScrollArea's contents are smaller, I want QScrollArea to shrink to that size, with rest of the available space used by addStetch.

However, currently, for small QScrollArea this works but when QScrollArea's contents are larger, it only expands to half of the available space.

I tried setting various Size Policies for the QScrollArea and the underlying scrolling widget but nothing works.

What's the trick to get this sorted?

Here's a snipped of my code [in Python but answers in C++ are very welcome]:

```
# My setup
self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
self.setLayout(self.layout)

scrollArea = QScrollArea()
self.layout.addWidget(scrollArea)
scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
scrollArea.setEnabled(True) 

self.scrollWidget = QWidget()
self.scrollLayout = QVBoxLayout()
self.scrollWidget.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)

scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)

# Now what I do is, I add bunch of widgets inside the self.scrollLayout
# and in the end, I perform a self.layout.addStretch() to push them up (verticle Alignment does same)
# Maximum height QScrollArea (scrollArea) gets is stuck at around 50% although I want to take all the space if necessary
```

I added ALL possible setSizePolicy(..) options

```
scrollArea.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding))
# and ALL others. None works. addStretch() still takes 50% minimum space and gets even more if QScrollArea's contents are smaller.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. 
It's necessary to override sizeHint to holding scrollarea's scrolling widget.
It's necessary to set maximum height to scrolling widget.
And it's necessary to place this widget inside a QVBoxLayout with addStretch() which pushes it to the top.

Comment: Could you improve this answer with an example of what you mean by "override sizeHint to holding scrollarea's scrolling widget"? I've been searching for an answer to this problem for hours! What did you see (https://xkcd.com/979/)?

Comment: sure. create a new class inheriting from "QtGui.QWidget" so essentially you are creating an new Widget. define a class function called "sizeHint" (this is called "overriding" since now your function returns the "sizeHint", not the default "sizeHint" function of "QWidget". do your calculations within this function (like calculate font sizes, margins etc. then return "QtCore.QSize(width, height)" (width and height being results of your calculations. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the very same problem and I think I found a solution. Do not add a stretch after the QScrollArea, but as last element inside the QScrollArea layout. So in your code, use `self.scrollLayout.addStretch()` instead of `self.layout.addStretch()`.

Answer (score 0):

> When QScrollArea's contents are smaller, I want QScrollArea to shrink
>   to that size, with rest of the available space used by addStetch.

If contents of QScrollArea are small, you can align them to the top and hide vertical scrollbar. In this case you won't need to add stretch to the main vertical layout.

If contents are larger than QScrollArea, it will take all available space.

I think, this is what you need.

Comment: Hello @hank. Thanks for the answer but this is not what I need. ;-) I am not talking about scrollbars here. I am talking about the size of the QSCrollArea and its stretching or shrinking. If available space is 100 and QSA's widget is 100+ I want QSA to have all the space. If QSA's widget is smaller than the available space, then I want QSA to be smaller and the empty space to stretch, pushing QSA to be aligned Top. You can see this from the code provided. I think this is a sizeHint issue. Do you know how to override size-hint?

Comment: @Phil I don't understand the way you want to use QSA. Why do you want QSA shrink but not its contents? The point of using QSA is to have a possibility to scroll over contents if they are _larger_ than their container. If contents are _smaller_ you don't need QSA to shrink. You can just align them to the top of QSA and hide scroll bar if needed. And by the way if you do `addStretch` there's always be an empty space in the layout, no matter what sizehints other widgets have.